# ggplot2 graph by certain name of data point (e.g. graph by state)

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I want to graph my data based on state name (see dataset below).

> Location  Year    Rate

Alabama   2000    30

Alabama   2001    40

*Insert more state names here*

I want to just graph it by a certain state with the x variable being Year and Y variable being Rate

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly:

```
library(tidyverse)
filter(df, Location == "Alabama")%>%
    ggplot(aes(Year, Rate)) + 
    geom_point()
```